# How to make youtube video added in the iframe accessible?

Tags: iframe, youtube, accessible

Please advise on how to make Youtube video embedded inside iframe accessible

Answer (score 0):

Find your video on YouTube and go to Share>Embed copy the code.

You code should look like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/your-video-code"></iframe>
```